# How to check if subsequent date variables occur on or after previous ones

Tags: r

I have 10 date variables, with the assumption that each subsequent variable is on or after the previous one (I have to check whether this assumption is true). I want to compare `TloCriminal1CrimeDetails1Di_0001` to `TloCriminal1CrimeDetails2Di_0001` `TloCriminal1CrimeDetails2Di_0001` to `TloCriminal1CrimeDetails3Di_0001`, ..., `TloCriminal1CrimeDetails9Di_0001` to `TloCriminal1CrimeDetails10D_0001`. Ideally, for each of those pairs, I want to output variables called, for example, `compare1to2`, `compare2to3`, ..., `compare9to10` that equal `1` if the second instance of the pair is on or after the first instance and `0` otherwise. If this isn't possible, then an "overall" variable that equals `1` if *any* of the pairs are "bad" (e.g., the second date is before the first) and `0` otherwise would suffice.

I tried working in SAS but realized it was quite impossible, so I swapped over to R. I don't have a good starting point. Here is a snippet of my dataset. Thank you for your help!

```
structure(list(TloCriminal1CrimeDetails1Di_0001 = structure(c(10197, 
12205, 15979, 12586, NA, 13787, 12913, 14616), label = "TloCriminal1CrimeDetails1DispositionDate", format.sas = "DATE", class = "Date"), 
    TloCriminal1CrimeDetails2Di_0001 = structure(c(10148, NA, 
    15979, 12586, NA, 14516, 12913, 14665), label = "TloCriminal1CrimeDetails2DispositionDate", format.sas = "MMDDYY", class = "Date"), 
    TloCriminal1CrimeDetails3Di_0001 = structure(c(10148, NA, 
    NA, 12586, NA, 13787, 12913, 14665), label = "TloCriminal1CrimeDetails3DispositionDate", format.sas = "MMDDYY", class = "Date"), 
    TloCriminal1CrimeDetails4Di_0001 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 12913, 14670), label = "TloCriminal1CrimeDetails4DispositionDate", format.sas = "MMDDYY", class = "Date"), 
    TloCriminal1CrimeDetails5Di_0001 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), label = "TloCriminal1CrimeDetails5DispositionDate", format.sas = "MMDDYY", class = "Date"), 
    TloCriminal1CrimeDetails6Di_0001 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), label = "TloCriminal1CrimeDetails6DispositionDate", format.sas = "MMDDYY", class = "Date"), 
    TloCriminal1CrimeDetails7Di_0001 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), label = "TloCriminal1CrimeDetails7DispositionDate", format.sas = "MMDDYY", class = "Date"), 
    TloCriminal1CrimeDetails8Di_0001 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), label = "TloCriminal1CrimeDetails8DispositionDate", format.sas = "MMDDYY", class = "Date"), 
    TloCriminal1CrimeDetails9Di_0001 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), label = "TloCriminal1CrimeDetails9DispositionDate", format.sas = "MMDDYY", class = "Date"), 
    TloCriminal1CrimeDetails10D_0001 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), label = "TloCriminal1CrimeDetails10DispositionDate", format.sas = "MMDDYY", class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), label = "CRIME_CHK")
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, I updated the dataset with a better sample. For the 17th individual, the first 4 columns aren't missing. I want to check column 1 and column 2, column 2 and column 3, column 3 and column 4, etc. If column 2 is on or after the date of column 1, then the variable is equal to 1. Otherwise, it is 0. I hope that is more clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can remove the first and last column and then do the comparison in a vectorized way

```
out <- +(df1[-1] >= df1[-ncol(df1)])
out[is.na(out)] <- FALSE
```

If it is to find `any` element in each column

```
colSums(out, na.rm = TRUE) == 0
```

Comment: Hi akrun! I think this is extremely close to what I want. I edited the dataset a few minutes ago to provide more instances with non-NA variables. Not sure if you've had a chance to use that updated dataset.

Comment: @user122514 I used the data from the update

Comment: @user122514 If you can show the expected output, I can crosscheck esp the `colSums` output

Comment: For the 2nd row, `TloCriminal1CrimeDetails1Di_0001` is `2003-06-02` and `TloCriminal1CrimeDetails2Di_0001` is `NA`. However, in dataset `out`, `TloCriminal1CrimeDetails2Di_0001` is `0`, which would indicate that the date in `TloCriminal1CrimeDetails2Di_0001` is before `TloCriminal1CrimeDetails1Di_0001`. Is there any way to not flag NA's?

Comment: @user122514 So, if the comparison is between a NA element and non NA, do you want as 0 or 1? i.e. `2003-06-02       NA`

Comment: @user122514 What would be if there are two `NA NA` at the same row

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you so much! I've accepted your answer, since I really wanted variables for each pair.

Answer (score 2):

You could loop with `sapply` over the columns and look where dthe `diff`erences are all greater than or equal to zero.

```
sapply(d, function(x) all(diff(na.omit(x)) >= 0))
# TloCriminal1CrimeDetails1Di_0001 TloCriminal1CrimeDetails2Di_0001 
#                            FALSE                            FALSE 
# TloCriminal1CrimeDetails3Di_0001 TloCriminal1CrimeDetails4Di_0001 
#                            FALSE                             TRUE 
# TloCriminal1CrimeDetails5Di_0001 TloCriminal1CrimeDetails6Di_0001 
#                             TRUE                             TRUE 
# TloCriminal1CrimeDetails7Di_0001 TloCriminal1CrimeDetails8Di_0001 
#                             TRUE                             TRUE 
# TloCriminal1CrimeDetails9Di_0001 TloCriminal1CrimeDetails10D_0001 
#                             TRUE                             TRUE
```

Or over the rows:

```
data.frame(check=apply(d, 1, function(x) all(diff(as.Date(na.omit(x))) >= 0)))
#   check
# 1 FALSE
# 2  TRUE
# 3  TRUE
# 4  TRUE
# 5  TRUE
# 6 FALSE
# 7  TRUE
# 8  TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This is probably for the "overall" variable. I realized I wasn't clear - I would want this overall variable for each individual. So, in my example, it would be great to have 8 rows with these variables. Sorry about that!

Comment: @user122514 I.e. you mean over the columns, right? See edit.